# sharing data between components and pages in ionic

Tags: angular, ionic3

Hello I am learning ionic and I want to access components files into homepage, when I mention component class links in homepage only first page is displaying remaining pages are not coming into page.

How to solve this or tell me any other way to achieve solve this problem?

---

> componentmodule.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ImageComponent } from './image/image';
import { IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { VideoComponent } from './video/video';
import { AudioComponent } from './audio/audio';
import { TextComponent } from './text/text';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        ImageComponent,
        VideoComponent,
        AudioComponent,
        TextComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        IonicModule
    ],
    exports: [
        ImageComponent,
        VideoComponent,
        AudioComponent,
        TextComponent
    ]
})
export class ComponentsModule { }
```

> appmodule.ts

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    ComponentsModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler},
    ActionSheet 

  ]
})
```

> app.html

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>
      Ionic Blank
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>

  <ion-card>
    <ion-card-header>
      Image
    </ion-card-header>
    <ion-card-content>
      <image></image>
    </ion-card-content>
  </ion-card>


  <ion-card>
    <ion-card-header>
      video
    </ion-card-header>
    <ion-card-content>
      <video></video>
    </ion-card-content>
  </ion-card>

  <ion-card>
      <ion-card-header>
        Audio
      </ion-card-header>
        <ion-card-content>
        <audio></audio>
      </ion-card-content>
    </ion-card>

</ion-content>
```

Comment: You can pass data with NavController, here is the tutorial: https://hackernoon.com/passing-data-between-pages-in-an-ionic-application-129b387c93b8

Comment: i have my code in components class so i want access those component files through pages. i know sharing data between pages but this one is troubling me

Comment: what exactly you want to access to the components files? variables? are you taking about the .ts file or the .html file?

Comment: thanks for the response in component html page i have mention buttons in div tag and it is solved.

Comment: @johnny glad you fixed it. You never put the component.html page code in your question btw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 ways that I know you can achieve passing data through components.

1) Using services (I prefer this one)

data.service.ts

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

    @Injectable()
    export class dataService {
        data: string;

        setData(data) {
            this.data = data;
        }

        getData(){
           return this.data;
        }
    }
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { dataService } from './server.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  constructor(private dataService: dataService){}

  getData() {
      retrun this.dataService.getData();
  }

}
```

2) Using the NavController

```
 //When you are using the push to switch pages you pass the data to the otherpage
    this.navCtrl.push(HomePage, {
          data: user
    });
```

In the page that you just went to (in this example HomePage), you access the data like this:

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
    this.user = navParams.get('data');
  }
```

Comment: Thank you sir, nice Info, but how to display value from data service to component.html ?

Comment: you will have to first access the service in the component, then from in the UI call whatever you need from the service that you ALREADY add in the component ts file